# How to configure jobTracker in hazelcast.xml to get optimized performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, mapreduce, hazelcast

Below is default configuration in hazelcast.xml,

```
<jobtracker name="default">
  <max-thread-size>0</max-thread-size>
  <!-- Queue size 0 means number of partitions * 2 -->
  <queue-size>0</queue-size>
  <retry-count>0</retry-count>
  <chunk-size>1000</chunk-size>
  <communicate-stats>true</communicate-stats>
  <topology-changed-strategy>CANCEL_RUNNING_OPERATION</topology-changed-strategy>
</jobtracker>
```

How to update this configuration to get better performance for map reducing in java application???

Answer (score 0):

The values you normally want to optimize are `chunk-size` and `communicate-stats`. First property is heavily depending on the way your mr job works and needs some trial and error, best is to keep reducers busy all the time (so depending on the reducing operation either bigger chunk size for heavy ops or smaller chunks for light operations). The `communicate-stats` deactivates transmission of statistical information which is normally not being used anyways.